# For some reason I started all my daemons, but when I try to use put command in using hadoop, it says connection failed

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, put, gedit

I've created a word file in my local folder in my hadoop folder:

```
gedit /usr/local/hadoop/words.txt
```

I then tried to use this put command:

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put words.txt input
```

But I've got this error:

```
put: Call From dachen-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

How should I fix this,  I started all my daemons, is my local host wrong?

Comment: *I think I started all my daemons*, Confirm whether Namenode is running!

Comment: @franklinsijo sorry i start all my daemons